# Add custom arguments for jQuery special event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a jQuery event plugin and I need to pass some data to a argument. So if I use it like this:

```
$(element).on('myevent', function(event, myargument) { console.log(myargument); });
```

I wan't to get the `myargument` object and it's properties (e.g. `name`), which is set in the handler.

So how would this work with the code below?

```
SmartScroll.myevent = {
    setup: function() {

        var myargumentData,
            handler = function(evt) {
                var _self = this,
                    _args = arguments;

                // The data I wan't to get
                myargumentData = {
                    name: "Hello"
                };

                evt.type = 'myevent';
                jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
            };

        jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(myargumentData, handler);

    },

    teardown: function() {
        jQuery(this).unbind('scroll', jQuery(this).data(myargumentData));
    }
};
```

Comment: would `jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, [_args, myargumentData]);` work?

Comment: No, nothing happens. The event is not even being triggered. Thanks for trying :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify an object passed to `add`.

```
$.event.special.foo = { add: function(h) {
    var hh = h.handler;
    h.handler = function(e, a) {
        hh.call(this, e, a * 2);
    };
} };
```

Now, let's bind the event:

```
$("body").on("foo", function(e, a) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

Fire the event and see what happens:

```
$("body").trigger("foo", [ 10 ]); // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
on: function( types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one )
```

According to the source.
so if i understand your problem , just do :

```
$(element).on('myevent',{my_data:"foo"},function(event) { 
  console.log(event.data.my_data); 
});
```

prints "foo"